# Incremental data load in ASO cube

Tags: essbase

I am using an ASO cube. We have two types of loads, Full Load and Incremental load. We are performing Full Load once in a day by clearing the cube and reload it. We need to run Incremental load in every 2 hours. I have aggregated data by running design aggregation. But now my incremental load time increased by 10 times.

Is there a way to load Incremental data into a cube which has aggregated data?

Please Help!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to load incremental data to an already aggregated cube as the agg views doesn't really change by data. Your aggregation views will get affected only when you perform a dimensional build that add more levels to the cube.

There are few things to consider
How are you performing incremental load? Direct load / create slice option?
Before performing the load, are you performing any clear operation? (Clear operation takes time when you have aggregations)
Are there any other loads / data push within this two hours timeframe that would potentially create a slice? (For example, when you have a replicated partition to push data, it will create a slice)

With all these points in mind, incremental load with create slice option would be the direction

Drop slice
Create buffer
Load data to the buffer
commit buffer with create slice option

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!! 

But when there is aggregated data in the cube then incremental load is taking 10 times more time. Do i need to clear the aggregates before Incremental data. How can i perform this activity with Incremental slice? I am new in Essbase hence dont know how we can resolve this with Incremental Slice. I am even not sure if we can use Incremental slice or not...

Please share your thoughts!!!